# How to connect oracle 10g using android in API 19

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, oracle10g

Need help for How to connect oracle 10g using android in API 19. Now I developing in API 19.
I can't connect to oracle database. Please give me a solution or source code. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is out of the box to use ORACLE DB Directly but you can do with the help of web connections you need to write web services which will connect to ORACLE DB and than use those web services in yours program for an example use the given tutorial to learn more, what we can say is 
The "normal" way to access your database would be to put a Restful server in front of it and use the HTTPS protocol to connect to the Restful front end.
You need following for this purpose

1) WebServer

2) A Database Stored in the webserver which is ORACLE DB in yours case

3) Webservices (json ,Xml...etc) whatever you are comfortable with

4) HTTP connection from android client to access web services.

for example and tutorials visit

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/27/android-phpmysql-connection-redone/#comment-7736

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/